# Switching letters in a character string with "#" if they aren't in a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, char

```
void funOne(char a[], string b, int aL, int bL) {
    int cnt[aL]={0};
    for(int i=0; i<bL; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<aL; j++) {
            if((char)b[i]==a[j]; {
                cnt[j]++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<bL; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<aL; j++) {
            if((char)b[i]==a[j]&&cnt=0) {
                b[i]='#';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

There is a char `arr[]={'H', 't', 'h', 's', 'e', 'i'};` and a character string `"Sherlock Holmes is a fiction private detective"`. Every character that's not in the array  should be replaced with `"#"` in the string.

The output should be

```
"She##### H###es is # #i#ti#n ##i##te #ete#ti#e"
```

There is something wrong with my code but I don't know what.

Comment: I think there's a lot wrong with your code. Poor choice of variable names, poor indentation, lack of spacing, incomplete code posted. All these things make it difficult for people to understand your code and so to answer. However I can see this `if((char)b[i]==a[j];{`, firstly `(char)` is completely unnecessary, `b[i]` is a char there's no need to cast it, secondly that `;` should be replaced by a `)`, add some spaces for legibility and you get `if (b[i] == a[j]) {`

Comment: `if((char)b[i]==a[j];{
          cnt[j]++;
           break;
      }`

You missclicked the if, you wrote it wrong

Comment: `int cnt[aL]`  This is not valid C+×.  Arrays in C++ must have the number of entries denoted by a constant expression, not a variable such as `aL`.

Comment: A note about casts. Any time you cast you are essentially telling the compiler, "Trust me. I know what I'm doing." You probably know what you are doing, but when you don't, you just turned off all of the compiler's built-in defenses. The more restrictive casts (`static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`)  will still do a bit of checking for you, but the c-style cast does exactly what you ask for no matter how bad an idea it may turn out to be. Use it only with great caution and only after exhausting all other avenues.

Answer (score 1):

If you were looking for an optimal solution to solve this problem, check this out! :)
The idea is to hash all the characters in the array and then check for their membership (**Checking - O(1)**) every time you iterate through the input string.

```
arr = set(['H', 't', 'h', 's', 'e', 'i'])
arr.add(' ') #so that whitespaces don't get replaced
input = 'Sherlock Holmes'
output = str()
for char in input:
    if char not in arr:
        output += '#'
    else:
        output += char

print output
```

This code runs in O(n) time but with O(n) space.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite buggy and unnecessarily complex. It can be simplified to something more like this:

```
void funOne(char a[], int aL, string &b) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < b.length(); ++i) {
        if (b[i] == ' ') continue;
        // check for other punctuation chars as needed... 
        bool found = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < aL; ++j) {
            if (b[i] == a[j]) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) b[i] = '#';
    }
}
```

Which can be simplified further by using the standard `std::find()` algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>

void funOne(char a[], int aL, string &b) {
    char *aEnd = a + aL;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < b.length(); ++i) {
        if (b[i] == ' ') continue;
        // check for other punctuation chars as needed... 
        if (std::find(a, aEnd, b[i]) == aEnd) b[i] = '#';
    }
}
```

Or, by using the `std::string::find_first_not_of()` method:

```
void funOne(char a[], int aL, string &b) {
    for(size_t i = b.find_first_not_of(a, 0, aL);
        i != string::npos;
        i = b.find_first_not_of(a, i + 1, aL))
    {
        if (b[i] == ' ') continue;
        // check for other punctuation chars as needed... 
        b[i] = '#';
    }
}
```